# Is a recorded telephone conversation admissible evidence if someone is being told the conversation is not being recorded?

Tags: criminal-law, privacy

Given the situation in which person A is recording a telephone conversation with person B, if person B asks person A if the conversation is being recorded and person A says ‘no’, is the conversation admissible evidence since person A lied about the conversation being recorded?
(For the sake of this question let us assume that we are in a state in which only one person needs to know that a conversation is being recorded and person A is not in law enforcement.)

Comment: In what jurisdiction?

Comment: Jurisdiction is USA.

Comment: Which state? There are different rules throughout the country.

Comment: Texas or any state with similar laws to Texas as it pertains to this issue.